# Prop data to child component

Tags: javascript, html

I use ngx-bootstrap to load tabs.

When I want to render a component in a dependency that is selected it doesn't work for me at all.
Check code:

```
<tabset class="w-100">
    <tab heading="test"
         id="test" 
         > 
    </tab>  
    <tab heading="Log"
         id="account-departments" >
         <div class="class">  
        </div> 
    </tab> v> 
    </tab> 
</tabset>
```

I need to use (testTab) function because (click) no work for this.

```
  public testCOmponent = null;
  @ViewChild(directiv) direcive!: direcyive;
  public activeTab: any;
```

If need console.log for both function inside when console.log(tab) inside onSelectTab function i got result.

If I console.log(t) inside render() function i always got undefined.

This example work:

I modeled on this:

I also made the adHost directive don't worry, that's not the problem.

I also tried to pass him an index of 0 or 1 not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using map instead of array for your components definitions:

```
public components = [HelloComponent, ByeComponent];
                    ||
                    \/
public components = { HelloComponent, ByeComponent };
```

Otherwise you have to search by index.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-componentfactoryresolver-example-imiach?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in my stackblitz?

Comment: Option 1 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foactroy-resolver-thsvcw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Option 2 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foactroy-resolver-tsvvhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-outlet.directive.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foactroy-resolver-axkhij?file=src%2Fapp%2FSecondComponent.component.ts `componentRef.instance[key] = this.tab.props[key];`

Comment: That's the same for option 1. You got componentRef, then you can pass any parameters to componentRef.instance

Comment: Second version should be clearer for you, but if you want first then it should look like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-foactroy-resolver-bkfxbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts